# Cosmos DB query return points outside the polygon using ST_Within

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Im using the query explorer in cosmosdb for searching points who are inside a polygon, my polygon in this sample is this (can be saw in [geojson.io](http://bl.ocks.org/d/d6e56db011c2e243b1254e8aef4ca33a))

```json
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
   {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry":{
              "type":"Polygon",
              "coordinates":   
                [[[-107.44131585954042, 24.801824950217672], 
                [-107.43361255454303, 24.801824950217672], 
                [-107.43361255454303, 24.791345071112183], 
                [-107.44131585954042, 24.791345071112183],
                [-107.44131585954042, 24.801824950217672]]]
      }, 
    "properties": {
        "name": "The Polygon"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-107.437779, 24.798064]
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "The point inside the polygon"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-107.39355, 24.792837]
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "The point offside the polygon"
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

but when i search in the query explorer, cosmosdb retrieve me both points
This is my query

```sql
SELECT * FROM root 
WHERE ST_Within(
    root["Punto"], {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates":   
    [[[-107.44131585954042, 24.801824950217672], 
      [-107.43361255454303, 24.801824950217672], 
      [-107.43361255454303, 24.791345071112183], 
      [-107.44131585954042, 24.791345071112183],
      [-107.44131585954042, 24.801824950217672]]]
      })
```

root["Punto"] is a valid GeoJSON Point, i checked it with the ST_ISVALID function, and also, if i use the function ST_DISTANCE, checking if the distance between the point and the polygon is greater than zero, the data retrieved is correct, but i don't know if this approach is correct

This is my second query using ST_DISTANCE

```sql
SELECT root.NombreUbicacion, root.Punto
from root
where ST_DISTANCE (root.Punto, {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates":   
                               [[[-107.44131585954042, 24.801824950217672], 
                               [-107.43361255454303, 24.801824950217672], 
                               [-107.43361255454303, 24.791345071112183], 
                               [-107.44131585954042, 24.791345071112183],
                               [-107.44131585954042, 24.801824950217672]]]
     }) > 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm send a mail to askcosmosdb@microsoft.com and they told me that i need to rearrange the polygon

> The behavior that you are seeing is because the points in the polygon are in the reverse order. If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial)
>
> > > "Points within a Polygon must be specified in counter-clockwise order. A Polygon specified in clockwise order represents the inverse of the region within it."

So, i change the query to this, a it works like a charm

```
SELECT * FROM root 
WHERE ST_Within(
root["Punto"], {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates":   
[[[-107.44131585954042, 24.801824950217672],
  [-107.44131585954042, 24.791345071112183],
  [-107.43361255454303, 24.791345071112183], 
  [-107.43361255454303, 24.801824950217672], 
  [-107.44131585954042, 24.801824950217672]]]
})
```

Thanks to the cosmosdb team

Answer (score 1):

Under "Spatial SQL built-in functions" section in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial#querying-spatial-types), you will see:

[image]

**Updated:**

As you said, using the point `{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[-107.437779, 24.798064]}` it returns the distance.

[image]

But based on my test with many other valid GeoJSON Points, `ST_DISTANCE (point_expr, polygon_expr)` often return 0, so using ST_DISTANCE (point_expr, polygon_expr) in **WHERE** condition as a filter may not work as expected.

[image]

I can not find official documentations or blogs that explain the above issue, if possible, you can contact the team on askdocdb@microsoft.com to get details about ST_DISTANCE (spatial_expr, spatial_expr).